# Show hidden div by selecting radio button, using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I show a `div` upon selecting a radio button?

What is the event for a radio button click?

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<style >  
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".static_class").click(function(){if($(this).val()==="Yes") $("#extra").show("fast"); else $("#extra").hide("fast");});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="14" value="Yes" class="static_class style1" />
&nbsp;Yes<br />

<input id="r2" type="radio" name="14" value="No" class="static_class style1" />&nbsp;No<br />

<div id="extra"> <br /><label>If yes, please specify.</label>    <input id="email" type="text" class="style" /></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine but make sure to put your code in [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".static_class").click(function(){
      if($(this).val() === "Yes")
        $("#extra").show("fast");
      else
        $("#extra").hide("fast");
    });
  });
</script>
```